# HTTPError: 401 Client Error: when accessing a website by python but not by chome browser

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt,time
import os
from  pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import datetime  as dt
from  pathlib import Path



df= ['ACC', 'ADANIENT', 'ADANIPORTS', 'AMARAJABAT', 'AMBUJACEM', 'APOLLOHOSP', 'APOLLOTYRE', 'ASHOKLEY', 'ASIANPAINT', 'AUROPHARMA', 'AXISBANK', 'BAJAJ-AUTO', 'BAJAJFINSV', 'BAJFINANCE', 'BALKRISIND', 'BANDHANBNK', 'BANKBARODA',
 'BATAINDIA', 'BEL', 'BERGEPAINT', 'BHARATFORG', 'BHARTIARTL', 'BHEL', 'BIOCON', 'BOSCHLTD', 'BPCL', 'BRITANNIA','CADILAHC', 'CANBK', 'CHOLAFIN', 'CIPLA', 'COALINDIA', 'COFORGE', 'COLPAL', 'CONCOR', 'CUMMINSIND', 'DABUR', 'DIVISLAB', 'DLF', 'DRREDDY', 'EICHERMOT', 'ESCORTS', 'EXIDEIND', 'FEDERALBNK', 'GAIL', 'GLENMARK', 'GMRINFRA', 'GODREJCP', 'GODREJPROP', 'GRASIM', 'HAVELLS', 'HCLTECH', 'HDFC', 'HDFCBANK', 'HDFCLIFE', 'HEROMOTOCO', 'HINDALCO', 'HINDPETRO', 'HINDUNILVR', 'IBULHSGFIN', 'ICICIBANK', 'ICICIPRULI', 'IDEA', 'IDFCFIRSTB', 'IGL',
 'INDIGO','INDUSINDBK','INFRATEL','INFY','IOC','ITC', 'JINDALSTEL', 'JSWSTEEL', 'JUBLFOOD', 'KOTAKBANK', 'L&TFH', 'LICHSGFIN', 'LT', 'LUPIN', 'M&M', 'M&MFIN', 'MANAPPURAM', 'MARICO','MARUTI','MCDOWELL-N','MFSL','MGL', 'MINDTREE','MOTHERSUMI', 'MRF', 'MUTHOOTFIN', 'NATIONALUM', 'NAUKRI','NESTLEIND','NMDC', 'NTPC','ONGC', 'PAGEIND','PEL', 'PETRONET',
 'PFC', 'PIDILITIND','PNB', 'POWERGRID','PVR', 'RAMCOCEM','RBLBANK', 'RECLTD','RELIANCE', 'SAIL','SBILIFE', 'SBIN','SHREECEM','SIEMENS','SRF','SRTRANSFIN','SUNPHARMA','SUNTV','TATACHEM', 'TATACONSUM','TATAMOTORS', 'TATAPOWER','TATASTEEL', 'TCS','TECHM', 'TITAN','TORNTPHARM', 'TORNTPOWER', 'TVSMOTOR', 'UBL','ULTRACEMCO','UPL', 'VEDL', 'VOLTAS','WIPRO', 'ZEEL']

for k in df:
    print(k)
    k1=k
    k=k.replace('&','%26')
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol="+str(k)
  #  headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data1 = response.json()
    if not  data1:
        print("empty @ "+ k)
    else:
     
        data=data1["records"]["data"]
        columns = pd.DataFrame(data[0]).transpose().columns
        final_data=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        for i in range(0,len(data)):
          z=pd.DataFrame(data[i])
          zz=z.transpose()
          if(len(zz.index)==3):
             final_data=final_data.append(zz.loc[[zz.index[2]]]) 
          elif(len(zz.index)==4):
             final_data=final_data.append(zz.loc[[zz.index[2]]]) 
             final_data=final_data.append(zz.loc[[zz.index[3]]])  
        final_data=final_data.reset_index() 
        final_data=final_data.rename(columns = {'index':'option_type'})
        final_data=final_data[(final_data['openInterest']>0)&(final_data['changeinOpenInterest']>0)].reset_index(drop=True)
        path=Path('E:\code and finance\Data\FNO\Equity\options',k1,(dt.datetime.today()).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+".xlsx")
        final_data.to_excel(path)
```

I was using the code to get the data but recently i started getting HTTPError: 401 Client Error: when accessing a website by python but not by chrome browser. What should i do to access the website like i sed to in python.
The link work in chrome but not in python

Comment: You should check out the API documentation for nseindia.com. It may be that you need to send your API credentials with the request

Comment: it's a free website with no documentation.  i fail to understand that how can a link be accessible in chrome but blocked when we send request via api.  can it be cookies ??                              url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol="+str("SBIN")

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
 NEED HELP WITH THIS PART ONLY

Comment: It seems like the site is detecting a cross-site scripting attack for that specific url ("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol="). When you make the request to url 'https://www.nseindia.com' it works (response.status_code == 200). Solution might have something to do with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).